# Fivetran Deleted Row Detection and Cost

Tags: etl, fivetran, elt

I'm very new to Fivetran and can't find clear documentation.

I have API with a 3rd party data aggregator that sends over a simple CSV. New rows are added each month and some rows may occasionally be deleted. The aggregator doesn't share deleted rows, so it's my understanding the only way to capture these deletes would be through nightly re-syncs. Is a re-sync of this type consider a "full refresh", incurring a charge for ALL rows or would we simply be charged for active rows.

I'm having trouble getting an answer from Fivetran support. Thanks.